# How to run two clients with parallel processes in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ejb

Good day.

I googled, but could not find the exact answer.

I created a simple EJB project in eclipse. I created a session full bean, added a business method, then created a simple java console client, deployed EJB project and started the server.

Then I run the client.

Is it possibly to run the second instance(process) to the same client in eclipse?

I would like to start running two processes for a single client app simultaneously.

I guess it must be something simple, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can run same project as many times as you want, just go to the .java file that contains the main(), right click it and select Run.

Comment: How can I do it? Should I hit the "run" button(ctrl + f11)?

Comment: Right click your Java class with main mehtod and select `Run AS -> Java application`

Comment: I opened two consoles. When I click Java class with main method and select Run as java application the client is started. I just see two views of the same data. If I hit the "run as java application" again there is nothing happens